# Python inserting a row in a 2Darray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have an 5x17511 2D array *(name = 'da'*) which made by a `pandas.read_csv(...)`

I also added one column for indexing like this: `da.index = pd.date_range(...)`

So my 2D array has 6x17511 size now.

I'd like to insert/append one more row to this 2D array, how to do this?

I already tried with: `np.insert(da,1,np.array((1,2,3,4,5,6)), 0)` but it says:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 17512), indices imply (6,
>   17511)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `DataFrame.ix[index] = row` ?

Comment: [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append) is designed for this

Comment: Indexing solution doesn't work:
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Append doesn't do anything somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed this is a numpy question rather than a pandas question ...

You could try vstack ...

```
import numpy as np
da = np.random.rand(17511, 6)
newrow = np.array((1,2,3,4,5,6))
da = np.vstack([da, newrow])
```

Which yields ...

```
In [5]: da
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0.50203777,  0.55102172,  0.74798053,  0.57291239,  0.38977322,
         0.40878739],
       [ 0.9960413 ,  0.22293403,  0.34136638,  0.12845067,  0.20262593,
         0.50798698],
       [ 0.05298782,  0.09129754,  0.40833606,  0.67150583,  0.19569471,
         0.75176924],
       ..., 
       [ 0.97927055,  0.44649323,  0.84851791,  0.05370892,  0.94375771,
         0.24508979],
       [ 0.85952039,  0.2852414 ,  0.85662827,  0.97665465,  0.65528357,
         0.71483845],
       [ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ,  4.        ,  5.        ,
         6.        ]])

In [6]: len(da)
Out[6]: 17512
```

And (albeit with different random numbers), I can access the top and bottom of the numpy array as follows ...

```
In [9]: da[:5]
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0.76697236,  0.96475768,  0.09145486,  0.27159858,  0.05160006,
         0.66495098],
       [ 0.62635043,  0.1316334 ,  0.66257157,  0.99141318,  0.77212699,
         0.17016979],
       [ 0.86705298,  0.11120927,  0.29585339,  0.44128326,  0.32290492,
         0.99298705],
       [ 0.74053894,  0.90743885,  0.99838398,  0.40713677,  0.17337202,
         0.56982539],
       [ 0.99136919,  0.13045787,  0.67881652,  0.03814385,  0.98036307,
         0.53594215]])

In [10]: da[-5:]
Out[10]: 
array([[ 0.8793664 ,  0.0392912 ,  0.8106504 ,  0.17920025,  0.26767578,
         0.98386519],
       [ 0.41231276,  0.02633723,  0.7872108 ,  0.60894162,  0.5358851 ,
         0.65758067],
       [ 0.10341791,  0.48079533,  0.1638601 ,  0.5470736 ,  0.7339205 ,
         0.60609949],
       [ 0.55320512,  0.12962241,  0.84443947,  0.81012583,  0.22057856,
         0.33495709],
       [ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ,  4.        ,  5.        ,
         6.        ]])
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried this, it works, but this add a lot of [] (square brackets) to my dataset and I don't need this. I hope you can understand what is my problem. ( I just need a 2D array, not vstack which separate rows with [] )

Comment: The square brackets are not really there - they just print that way so you can get a sense of the structure of the data.

Comment: But after this I can't index my array like this:
da[:'150']

IndexError: invalid slice

Before vstack I could

Comment: did you try da[:150] - ie. without the single quotes - and is that what you meant - the first 150 lines of the 2D array?

Comment: Yes, of course I tried without quotes, didn't help me. Yes I'd like to select the first 150 lines of 2D array.